installing plugins through pip correctly
I am trying to edit some code through idle, and I am trying:
pip install --

through command prompt, however it does not work and command prompt even says python is not detected on my computer even if I do:
python -m pip install --

If I have python installed through Microsoft Store however, downloading plugins works as intended, but I cannot run the code through normal idle as it says I have none of the plugins installed. When I try to open the file with Microsoft Python it won't open, and Microsoft Python does not have its own version of idle.
Does anyone have any ideas on whats happening and how to fix it?

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

where do you run pip? In console or in python interpreter? Did you try to use /full/path/to/pip and /full/path/to/python? And maybe you have to set /full/path/to/python in some settings in IDE

maybe don't install it from microsoft store but download installer from official page python.org - it should install Python with IDLE.

might be due to python is not installed in your path variable

You might not have Python install on your computer, install Python here if you haven't.
The python command might not work due to the version of python, try python3 or py or py3 instead of python.
About pip, you might haven't install it, read this to install it.
If you want to use the pip command without python -m in front of it, add it to %PATH%.
Remember to put Python in %PATH%, too.

Zip is on Windows and should be using py on the command line.

installing it as py was how i made it work with the main download version from the browser, so it worked as py -m pip install
